# Error in Perl Code

Tags: perl

In spite of having correct values for all the scalar values present in the arguments, This section of code keep getting failed because of the `$rc` value.I am not sure how the `$rc` value is getting calculated here.

```
@args = ("$isql_exe", "-U$user", "-P$password", "-S$server", 
         "-D$database", "-i$tmp_sql_file", "-o$tmp_err_file");  

print $log_file "Truncating stage tables\n";
$rc = 0xffff & system (@args); # <--- what this does?

if ($rc != 0) {
    $rc &= 0x00ff;
    print $log_file "Error Executing SQL command script $rc $?\n";
    $rc = 1;
} ## end if
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: In the line you have trouble understanding, `$rc` is set to the lowest 16 bits of the return value from the `system` command. If there is an error, it is being returned by the external command as an error code, and it is not directly a problem with that line of Perl.

Comment: Do you really have a variable named `$isql_exe`, or is that the variable `$i` plus the string `sql_exe`?

Comment: actually , it shouldn't go in the if condition.. so it is not truncating the table..it is printing like this :Error Executing SQL command script 0 65280 as mentioned in the print statement.

Comment: So, i just want to understand the how the $rc is getting its value?

Comment: @Praveenks `&` is the bitwise and operator, `&=` is the assignment version of it (`$x &= $y` => `$x = $x & $y`). Seen in perldoc perlop. The `system` command is described in `perldoc -f system`.

Comment: ok, so system() is just like exec() means it will execute the isql.exe based on the value in @args.if the executing is successful than it should return 0, right? but then what is the use of 0xffff?

Comment: @Praveenks TLP's comments are spot on, but you will need to follow his advice and read the [man page for perl system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) to understand it properly.

Comment: @TLP, re: `$isql_exe`, that's likely the path to the [SQL Server ISQL.EXE utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214007(v=SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: @pilcrow Its often a good idea to exclude obvious mistakes first, so I wondered he meant `${i}sql_exe`, but he never replied, so he probably did not understand that. As you say, that it is a path to an executable is likely, if one were to guess. And just because someone says they have "all the correct variables" doesn't mean they actually do.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. "$isql.exe" is the path to the isql.exe utility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$rc = 0xffff & system (@args);` is very wrong.

```
$ perl -E'say system("non-existent")'
-1

$ perl -E'say 0xFFFF & system("non-existent")'
65535
```

This code is far better:

```
system(@args);

my $rc = 0;
if    ($? < 0   ) { $rc=1; print $log_file "Error Executing SQL command script: $!\n"; }
elsif ($? & 0x7F) { $rc=1; print $log_file "SQL command script killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n"; }
elsif ($? >> 8  ) { $rc=1; print $log_file "SQL command script exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"; }
```

It's better because it doesn't use `$rc` for multiple purposes; it reports error more accurately; and it's much clearer to read.

For a `$?` of `65280`, it will say `exited with error 255`. Exit codes are specific to the program giving them, and are often meaningless beyond being zero or non-zero. That's why they print error messages.